# Swift cannot convert json array to a NSArray

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to get a json data from webpage and put it into my app. I have search so many things online and do not find any of them solve my problem.

The sample json is here

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Clean Archutecture","ISBN":"9780134494166","phone":null,"email":null,"comment":null,"last_update":"2018-03-10 22:53:29","price":"40","type":"sell"},{"id":"2","name":"Math Book","ISBN":null,"phone":null,"email":null,"comment":null,"last_update":"2018-03-10 22:53:54","price":null,"type":"want"},{"id":"3","name":"abc","ISBN":null,"phone":"hi","email":null,"comment":null,"last_update":"2018-03-11 19:58:00","price":"14.5","type":"want"},{"id":"4","name":"asd","ISBN":"1234","phone":"546","email":"dgf@asdc.com","comment":"234","last_update":"2018-03-11 19:59:57","price":"123","type":"want"}]
```

Swift code:

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class Books: NSObject{

    let urlRootPath = "http://maichongju.com/dbbs.php"
    let method = "GET" //This is design for the php

    func getData(type:String){
        var result = NSArray()
        let urlPath: String = urlRootPath+"?method=GET&size=ALL"
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data,response, error in

            if error != nil{
                print("error:!!  \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            do {
                result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
                print(result )
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }

            //print(result)

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Error message is

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}

I have double check my json data, i put it into online json view and it show perfectly fine. And I really dont know how to fix this problem

Comment: Your 'urlPath' is invalid.

Comment: "request.httpMethod = "POST"  What is it for?

Comment: Please write Swift code, not Objective-C like Swift code. In other words, drop `NSObject`. Replace `NSArray` with a Swift array. Replace `NSMutableURLRequest` with `URLRequest`.

Comment: The error makes it clear that the result you get back from the server is not actually JSON. Convert `data` to a `String` to see what you are actually getting back.

Comment: @rmaddy How can i convert the data into a String

Comment: I found the problem, I think i have the URL correct. But for some reason, what I see on the webpage is not what i get from the app. And i dont know why is that happen. I got something regular <html> body

Comment: why you put request.httpMethod = "POST" ?

Comment: Try to add a "application/json" to your request. That's maybe why it's rendering HTML instead of JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to force cast json response

do like this:

```
jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
```

2. Convert it like this as this is `Array` of `Dictioanry` objects

   `if let responseArray: [[String:Any]] = jsonResponse as? [[String:Any]] {
          // DO HERE
   }`

I hope this will work for you

For safe side you https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire for Network request and for JSON : https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

**Update**:

```
let urlPath: String = urlRootPath+"?method=GET&size=ALL"
```

i think is incorrect, In your body you have added `POST` but in URL you are appending `method=GET`

```
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Comment: According to the error message forced or safe unwrapping makes no difference.